tl_trim_spaces and tl_if_blank?
Is there any input for which, once processed with tl_trim_spaces could lead to tl_if_blank being true AND tl_if_empty being false?

No, that's not possible.
\tl_if_blank:nTF ignores any number of spaces but nothing else since it's using an undelimited TeX argument for its processing.
\tl_trim_spaces:n loops and removes all spaces from either end of a token list variable until there are no spaces on the end left, without touching anything else.
\tl_if_empty:nTF is the base test that \tl_if_blank:nTF is building upon (after removing possible spaces via TeX's argument grabbing logic).
Let's compare the two definitions:
> \tl_if_empty:nTF=\long macro:
#1->\if:w \scan_stop: \tl_to_str:n {#1}\scan_stop: \__prg_TF_true:w \fi: \use_ii:nn .

> \tl_if_blank:nTF=\long macro:
#1->\if:w \scan_stop: \__kernel_tl_to_str:w \exp_after:wN {\use_none:n #1?}\scan_stop: \__prg_TF_true:w \fi: \use_ii:nn .

As you can see, the only difference between the two is the \exp_after:wN that expands \use_none:n once and the trailing ? (which is there so that \use_none:n doesn't yield a low level TeX error on empty/blank input and so that there still is a token if the input only contains a single non-space token or brace group). So if #1 contains no non-space tokens this is equivalent to \tl_if_empty:nTF after the expansion of \use_none:n.
